# #define NSLog(p1, ...); does not work in Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog, ios5.1

I use

```
#define NSLog(p1, ...);
```

to put logging off in my code. Then I use

```
//#define NSLog(p1, ...);
```

to put logging on in my code
This doesn't seem to have any effect now that I use Xcode 4.3.1.

Am i doing something wrong? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: Can you put an example? I dont understand your code so much

Answer (score 0):

Use `#define kMyString @"This is my string text!"` and then use `NSLog(@"String: %@",kMyString);`

Comment: Thank you for reacting but this is not what I mean. What i do is some kind of trick to easily switch off the logging

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The difference with the previous version of Xcode is that

```
  #define NSLog(p1, ...);
```

doesn't work anymore when i put this code in the .m file. It only works from the .h file